# I'm trying to lock file exclusively on read

Tags: java, locking

I'm trying to lock a file exclusively on read.

I am using Java 7 on Windows 7.

The files are copied to a directory, and then I want to to read them correctly after copy. That's why I'm trying lock file exclusively on read.

But my program read file in the middle.
Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks!

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class FileLockMove {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
        File dir = new File("c:/test_source/");
        while(true){
            for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                try (FileChannel fc = (new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")).getChannel()){
                    FileLock lock = fc.tryLock();
                    if(lock != null){
                        System.out.println("lock is not null\t" + file.getName());
                        System.out.println("addBody: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\t" + file.length());
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("lock is null\t" + file.getName());
                        continue;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("fail:" + file.getName()+"\t" + e.getMessage());
                }
                try {
                    Files.move(file.toPath(), fs.getPath("c:/test_dest/",file.getName()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Originally, the copy file is not Java, but I created a copy of my program slowly to confirm that I can lock exclusively.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class FileCopySlow{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "C:/test_orig/";
        String dst ="C:/test_source/";
        File file = new File(source);
        File[] files = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                if(name.matches(".*\\.bmp")){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        for(File f: files){
            copyStream(f, dst);
        }

    }

    static void copyStream(File source,String dst){
        try(BufferedInputStream br = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source))){
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dst+source.getName()));
            byte[] buff = new byte[100];
            int len = -1;
            while((len = br.read(buff)) >-1){
                out.write(buff,0,len);
                out.flush();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            out.close();
            System.out.println(source.getName() + "\tfinish");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you defined a `copyStream` method yourself, instead of `Files.copy(InputStream source, OutputStream sink)`  ? Cause you want to achieve a "slow" copy?    Another question is why you want lock on each read? multiple read will not be a problem in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I need "slow copy". Another question's answer is I don't know how to lock multiple files. I just want to read files after copy. Now I read file inspite of copying is not finished. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that you should improve your question, which is not clear enough, what is the relationship between your two parts of codes?  Why you need a "slow copy" ? If you just want to read files after copy, you can simply call  `Files.copy.(Path source, OutputStream out)` method, which will blocking until the copy is done: This method may block indefinitely writing to the output stream (or
     * reading from the file), then you can read the copied files via `Files.readAllLines(Path path, Charset cs)`.

Comment: In my situation,copy program is not java.Second part is sample program  to make clear the first part can not lock exclusively.I try to get exclusive lock on read file,even if what program copy file. Thanks.